# Change file manager on Ubuntu to Dolphin from flatpak

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 19.04, filemanager

Thanks to this ["How can I have latest Dolphin file manager on Ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075924/how-can-i-have-latest-dolphin-file-manager-on-ubuntu) I was able to install Dolphin [flatpk] on Ubuntu 19.04. However if I click on any entry like "Documents", "Pictures", etc. on [Arc Menu](https://gitlab.com/LinxGem33/Arc-Menu) Nautilus opens. I am not able to change that behavior to Dolphin..

I tried to alter this common script to match with Dolphin, but with no success:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was pretty easy:

1. To get the application name of Dolphin:
   `flatpak list
   Description           Application Version Zweig  Arch   Origin  Installation
   Dolphin - Filemanager org.kde.dolphin     stable x86_64 flathub system`
2. Change default filemanager:
   `xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

My question is similar to [Flatpak applications use nautilus instead of Dolphin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040293/flatpak-applications-use-nautilus-instead-of-dolphin), but that got no real answer IMO.

If you want to get to know more about Flatpak file paths: [Link](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1286)