# Flatpak and Snap apps open vscode instead of the file manager

Tags: snap, filemanager, dolphin, visual-studio-code, flatpak

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 and Flatpak 1.6.5. Dolphin is my default File Manager
[image]

when I open a directory from a Flatpak app such as [DropBox](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.dropbox.Client) or [Cryptomator](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.cryptomator.Cryptomator), it opens it in Visual Studio Code instead of Dolphin. This doesn't happen if I open a directory from a non Flatpak app. Also `xdg-open ~` as expected opens Dolphin. So it seems to be a Flatpak issue.

Visual Studio Code is installed with apt, [the official way to install it](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).

This other question seems similar: [Flatpak applications use nautilus instead of Dolphin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040293/flatpak-applications-use-nautilus-instead-of-dolphin)

I notice the same issue opening a directory from [Chromium Browser](https://snapcraft.io/chromium) installed as a Snap.

### Update

This is the [issue I have opened](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/842) on Github on the repo `flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal`

### Update

I have upgraded my system to Kubuntu 22.04, the issue seems to be solved for Flatpak apps but still affects Snap apps.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a few months old now, but I found this looking for the same issue. In my case, a flatpak app was opening VS Code but only in some situations and other it was correctly opening my file picker. I'm using KDE so I wanted it to always open dolphin but it was a GTK flatpak so I thought that might be the issue. Turns out, it's because VS Code prepends itself to inode/directory in /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache. Moving VS Code to the end of that line and dolphin to the start fixed the issue. Note that dolphin did show as the default in the settings app. My guess is KDE versus GTK, the settings app only showed the KDE settings and the flatpak was searching the GTK way. Or something.

Comment: Different issue I think. If I `grep vscode  /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` I have only `x-scheme-handler/vscode=code-url-handler.desktop;` and it's down to the penultimate line of the file.